# Evaluating $\int t \exp(2t) \sin(2t) \mathrm dt$

Tags: calculus

Can someone show me how to evaluate

$$\int te^{2t}\sin 2t\,dt$$

without using a complex analysis approach? Thanks,

David

Comment: Your title and body disagree on the trig function.  Which is it?  The same techniques will work on both.  The $2$s go away with a u substitution, then integrate by parts to get rid of the polynomial. [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x*e%5E%282x%29*cos%282x%29) can do it

Comment: @Ross Millikan 3 Fixed my typo.

Comment: Integration by parts.

Answer (score 1):

There is no complex analysis when you write with $x=2t$
$$\int t\,e^{2t}\sin 2t\,dt=\frac 14\Im \int x\,e^{x}e^{ix}\,dx=\frac 14\Im \int x\,e^{(1+i)x}\,dx$$ One single integration by parts gives the result.

Answer (score 0):

1. $\int e^{t}\sin (t)\,dt$ is known.
2. By (1), $\int e^{2t}\sin (2t)\,dt$ is known.
3. $\int te^{2t}\sin (2t)\,dt$ is known with integration by parts: Let $u=t$ and $dv = e^{2t}\sin (2t)\,dt$, where $dv$ is known by (2).